# How can I verify that my AJAX crawling settings are working

Tags: ajax, dynamic, web-crawler, snapshot, google-crawlers

I tried to do fetch as Google with this URL 
    /54.86.51.30/search-space-for-rent/Houston#! 
and I got this from result
[image]

And on the server log I see google accessed my site with this url
   "/54.86.51.30/search-space-for-rent/Houston" instead of
   "/54.86.51.30/search-space-for-rent/Houston?_escaped_fragment_="

But If i do fetch as Google for this url /54.86.51.30/search-space-for-rent/Houston?_escaped_fragment_= than I do get HTMLsnapshot of my page.
[image]

Why I am not getting HTML Snapshot for /54.86.51.30/search-space-for-rent/Houston#! as It does have "#!" at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because google has changed the "fetch as google" works some time around May/June 2014. You need to rewrite your pretty url yourself, exactly as you did it above. I am a bit disappointed that google has dropped this feature, but found a good alternative to test my hashbang urls and that is [Facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/).

Comment: Aahaa!!! But they did not update their documentation for that....Thanks For your reply!!!